# Exception not being raised when it should be

Tags: python, windows

if I open notepad it will print 'y' but if notepad is not opened it wouldn't print 'n'. I can't think of any errors in a 13 lines code that simple. im going crazy. I would need some help.

```
import psutil
from time import sleep, time

name = "notepad.exe"

for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    try:
        if proc.name().lower() == name.lower():
            print("y")
            sleep(1)
    except:
        print("n")
        sleep(1)
```

Comment: You are using the wrong tool for this. No exception if being thrown by this code. You probably want to just pull the conditional out of the try-block and add a simple `elif`` to the conditional instead

Comment: Yeah I thought about that, but I still couldn't believe how this is not working.

Comment: The better question is "why would this work?" Your code never throws any exceptions so the `except` block would never execute

Comment: Got it now. I thought like if an "if" statement wouldn't run it would throw an exception. Edit: If the "if" statement is in the try block.

Comment: did you mean it like this `for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        if proc.name().lower() == name.lower():
            print("y")
            sleep(1)           
        elif proc.name().lower() != name.lower():
            print("n")
            sleep(1)`

Edit: sorry for bad post quality, also its not working. Edit2: it always prints the "elif" statement even if notepad is open. Edit3: `name = "notepad.exe"`

Comment: essentially, there could be a lot of reasons why its not printing `"y"` but since that's beyond the scope of the original question you will be better served by opening a new question specific to that issue